# How to create a string with sprintf

Tags: r, json, printf

I would like to create a string like JSON format using the `sprintf` function.
I use this code:

```
elements_list = sprintf('{"id":"%s",
                          "top": "%s",
                          }', 5, 4)
```

But the result when I print the string is like this:

```
"{"id\":\"5\",\"top\":\"4\"}"
```

with `"\"` character everywhere, any help?

Thanks!

Comment: The `""` are escaped. Check `cat(element_list)` to see actual string.

Answer (score 1):

This should work - you don't need all the double-quotes inside the expression:

```
elements_list = sprintf('{id:%s top: %s}', 5, 4)
elements_list
# [1] "{id:5 top: 4}"
```